# How do I go about plug-able features and modules in Java software architecture?

Tags: java, architecture, software-design

I am about to start a new software project. I know that a good planing and software design leads, eventually, to a successful software project.

I am wondering, How do I go about a software architecture where you have a core module and other plug-able or add-on modules. The modules can be excluded and included based on clients needs and pricing and can be turn off and on based on clients own configurations.

For example, let us take some financial software and there is a module that does statistics about the market clients. Then some client- of my product - does not want to buy this module because they don't need it. What is the best way to design my architecture so that I can exclude with the least efforts and least code touching- without touching it at all if possible  - ? 
we can discuss several topics like package organization, using some frameworks like JPF, Interface and Inheritance and so on ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very very broad topic for summarizing it in stackoverflow discussion but lets try. The first really basic need in my opinion is to have a very detailed knowledge of the domain the software is going to serve. Before starting any design not mentioning about coding, the first thing is to have the necessary know-how of the domain.

Once you have that, you start defining some core modules which will be the fundamentals of your software. Typically for example you would need **network, configuration, io, core, persistence, tools**, etc. Personally i define one module with a package for example if i say **core** module i would refer to packages such as: `com.example.core com.example.core.utils`. Core packages are more infrastructure work. like preparing the ground before start building the real software.

**Having on a blackboard the design** of separate modules and their dependencies, a good practice is to use maven as the build tool. Design each module as a separate project and include it as a dependency via maven for other modules/projects. And this will form the plug-gable modules. within each module provide configuration support (based on xml, json or even plain txt files) so certain features can be turned on/off or modified. So based on license agreement you can easily provide a build with the required modules and modify inside each module the feature configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very Interesting Question that developers often take for granted.

Some Developers think just jumping into code generates the ideas, requirements and functionality overtime - This however may be true but often jeopardizes Good Architecture, Flexibility, and Robustness.

For a new Software, Time should be spent in Requirement gathering (even if possible, reading and getting both broad and specific understanding about the domain and its current process flows, also rules and other constraints.

1. Get more understanding of the Domain
2. Come up with a Requirement Document
3. Identify the key Objects in the domain
4. Create a simple Model Diagram and identify the relationships in a broad context
5. Identify Major Use cases

Although this times may seem being wasted and also dead ends in generation of ideas and requirements, looking back, one would always appreciate the time sacrificed to carry this out

I also recently started a new Software project and had really tough time doing the Planning, but on the long run. Both I and others who looked through the Requirement Documentation and Diagrams appreciated it.

Coming specific to your question, Meta-Programming is a very good way to model a core module that scales ............Look into this [openMRS](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core) opensource software to have an idea of a very good core Architecture